# Do not see any change on runtime eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

I Change an activity background color in eclipse,but I don't any change in run time. why?
this is activity XML code,I use android:background="#ff0000" to change background cokor:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        tools:content=".TestingDetailsActivity"
        android:background="#ff0000">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExistsTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ExamList" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and java code:

```
package com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestingDetailsActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnExistsTest;
    protected void onCreate() {
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);
        btnExistsTest=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExistsTest);
    btnExistsTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(TestingDetailsActivity.this,ExamListActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
    })  ;
    }


}
```

Comment: You'll need to give us more details here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually uninstall the APK file from your phone and then re-run the app from your IDE. Sometimes these kind of glitches happen.